# How to animate the CABasicAnimation in background after the home button is pressed?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm new in ios development. I'm using wheel images in my project.The animation is working fine in foreground mode. After that I pressed the home button.now i relaunch the app the wheel animation is not working. this is my code:

```
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"]; animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2*M_PI];
animation.duration = 1.0f;
animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
[imageLeft.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];
```

Comment: could you please elaborate ?

Comment: where you have written this code?

Comment: I wrote this code in viewController.h

Comment: Why do you want to fire an animation in the background? Nobody will ever see it.

Comment: I would suggest you take a look into Apple's Documentation on view controllers life cycle https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thats right. but now i relaunch the app the animation is not working.

Comment: you problably implement the method in the wrong place. also when working with CoreAnimation the animation is fired when the `[addAnimation]` is called.

Comment: I want to animate the UIImageview in foreground mode when i relaunch the app.

Comment: I want to animate the UIImageview in foreground mode when i relaunch the app.

Comment: try, put this code in viewDidAppear method...

Comment: in which method you that code?

Comment: Rotating the circle image

Comment: what method, viewDidLoad or somewhere else?

Comment: where you wrote this code ?

Comment: move the above code to viewDidAppear or ViewWillAppear method.

Comment: I put the code in viewDidAppear and ViewWillAppear. but animation is not working. Still now i'm getting same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(addAnimation:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];

}

- (void)addAnimation:(NSNotification *)notificaiton
 {
 CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
 animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2*M_PI];
 animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
 animation.duration = 4.0f;
 animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
 [imageLeft.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];
 [imageRight.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];
 }
```

Comment: Jeffrey's answer should be the accepted solution instead.

Answer (score 88):

#### Swift 4.2 Updated

Ah I figured it out - use this and all the cases like stopping after going into the background will be fixed.

```
animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
```

Comment: this is the best AND simplest answer I've found for this problem. Used it within a custom control

Comment: `.removedOnCompletion` is in BOOL type.. YES/NO is much better.. Thank you for this sir.

Comment: @0yeoj Yes, use YES/NO for Obj C. This code that I wrote is in Swift.

Comment: Using Xcode 8.2 and swift 3 this does not work. When returning from background, my animation is "replayed" on top of the old one.

Comment: Simplest solution. A lot better than adding an observer and identifying willEnterForground.

Comment: but in background the new animation will not fire

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(addAnimation:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];

}

- (void)addAnimation:(NSNotification *)notificaiton
 {
 CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
 animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2*M_PI];
 animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
 animation.duration = 4.0f;
 animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
 [imageLeft.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];
 [imageRight.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you leave the app, all animations are removed from their layers: the system calls removeAllAnimations on every layer. So if you want to continue animation, then u can listen to UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification and start the animation again.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (![_imageLeft.layer animationForKey:@"SpinAnimation"])
    {
         CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
         animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2*M_PI];
         animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
        animation.duration = 4.0f;
        animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
        [_imageLeft.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];
    }


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(addAnimation:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)addAnimation:(NSNotification *)notificaiton
{
   if (_imageLeft && ![_imageLeft.layer animationForKey:@"SpinAnimation"])
   {
       CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
        animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2*M_PI];
        animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
        animation.duration = 4.0f;
        animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
        [_imageLeft.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];
    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: How to use UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification in viewController or Appdelegate method.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, it works coding like following:

```
        animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
```

But, if it did not work as expected, you may miss some code:

```
        animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
```

Answer (score 1):

When an app goes into the background, the system removes all animations from its layers.  In your `viewWillAppear:` method, register for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`.  When you observe the notification, add the animation again.  Unregister for the notification in `viewWillDisappear:`.